# Shortening function name with variable

Tags: javascript

I would like to call some functions by shorter alias in order to minimize code size.

```
(function(){
    var t = document.getElementById;
    t('element-id');
})();
```

This piece of code gives `Error: Could not convert JavaScript argument`. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign a function to a different variable, it's `this` value changes. Since `getElementById` expects `this` to be an element, you're getting an error.

If you're in an environment where you can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), use it:

```
(function(){
    var t = document.getElementById.bind(document);
    t('element-id');
})();
```

This'll ensure that `t`'s `this` will stay the `document` object.

---

If you can't use `bind`, you'll have to create an intermediary function:

```
(function() {
    function t (id) {
        document.getElementById(id);
    }
    t('element-id');
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

As Joseph says, the `this` value changes and it messes up the function. Try the following:

```
var t = function(i) {return document.getElementById(i);};
```

Answer (score 2):

so in this case, you could do

```
let t = (id) => document.getElementById(id);
t("myElement")
```

this implies use of an arrow function that returns the object just like `document.getElementById("")` would.